# Node.js error ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets

My client (PHP) is repeatedly a message to a Node.js `net.Server`, and gets an unexpected error.

Part of the server:

```
socket.on('error',function(err){
    logger.emit('error',err);
});

[Error: write ECONNABORTED] code: 'ECONNABORTED', errno: 'ECONNABORTED', syscall: 'write'

[Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'
```

If I send the messages one by one, I don't get an error.

**Edit: posting `client.php`:**

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    $sendmessage = $_GET['msg'];
    $host = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";//server ip 
    $port = 3030;

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");

    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

    $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Couldn't connect to server: [$errorcode] $errormsg");

    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec" => 60, "usec" => 0));

    socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");

    $serverresponse = socket_read($socket, 1024,PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("Could not read server response: [$errorcode] $errormsg"); 

    echo $serverresponse;
}
```

Comment: Can you add complete code for your server? If it's long, please make a simple self-contained example.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you get are thrown because the TCP connection is closed by the PHP client, so I guess you got a problem in the client.

*Edit:*

Building a plain TCP socket client with this is not a really simple task. If you're lucky you're just missing the `socket_close($sock);` ([php.net Sockets Examples](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php)).

I would really recommend just using the HTTP protocol:

- with PHP `HttpRequest` ([php.net HttpRequest](http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php))
- with NodeJS the `http` library ([Blog post on using nodejs http lib](http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs))

This will make it all much simpler, and work pretty much out of the box.

Comment: do I need to stay open my client socket ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you'll get errors like this. You need to keep it open until you have the answer. This is part of the http spec. Have you made a custom http client or do you dispose just after sending?

Comment: Oh I see now it isn't HTTP, sorry. Will just try to extend the answer.

Comment: Did the extension to my answer help, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I can't use http because my client are not browser it is device

Comment: Using a device (which kind?) should not limit you not to use http, as long as you have a library supporting it. It's just a protocol. Have you checked if you got the libs?